# What is the Sugihara Trading System?

Tags: statistics, forecasting, quant-trading-strategies, strategy, trading-systems

I recently heard the term Sugihara Trading System. I guess it might be some trading strategy or a special model to predict trends in market data, but I couldn't find out anything about it. Does anyone know what's behind this term?

Comment: Is [this](http://www.signonsandiego.com/news/2011/aug/28/ah-chaos/) what you want?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Yet another super duper trading strategy spam.

Comment: @asmaier: You can accept one of the answers if you are satisfied by it :-)

Answer (score 7):

I don't think that it is a real applicable trading system but it is more general work concerning the connection between chaos and financial markets.

A good starting point is this (relatively recent) article:
http://deepeco.ucsd.edu/~george/publications/08_ecology_bankers.pdf

You can find his publications here: http://sio.ucsd.edu/Profile/gsugihara#pubs

Comment: His most cited paper seems to be "Nonlinear forecasting as a way of distinguishing chaos from measurement error in time series", see http://scholar.google.de/scholar?cluster=14020791999996142656&hl=de&as_sdt=0,5